# URL Fetch Google Compute Engine from App Engine (Standard Env)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have an application running on app engine standard environment (java) and an elasticsearch running on a compute instance both belonging to the same project. How can I access this instance in a "secure way", for e.g with the internal IP. I already enabled the tcp:9200 port in the firewall rules.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem was related with the elasticsearch configuration file. I followed elastic documentation and everything seem to work now.

Answer (score 0):

If you open your cloud console, and navigate to app-engine's instances page, there you can find an internal IP for each instance.

You can also do this via command line if you have [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/) installed.

`gcloud compute instances list`

This IP is internal to your project and can be accessed by other compute engine instances in the project.